# powershell to report when a server uptime is above threshold

Tags: windows, powershell, server, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to create a powershell script that check all the servers (Windows 2012 R2) on the domain, and send an e-mail report if the server up time is over the threshold that you set in the script (this case is 30 days). But I have a problem, looks like the Function do not work with my ForEach loop.

My code so far:

```
# Variables for sending the report
$sender = "serviceaccount@domain.com"
$receiver = "administrator@domain.no"

# Find all the servers in the domain that need to be checked
Get-ADComputer -filter * -properties operatingsystem | where {$_.operatingsystem -match "server"} | select name | export-csv c:\script\serverlist.csv -NotypeInformation

$computer = import-csv .\serverlist.csv

# Set the Threshold Limit and Deadline
$Threshold = -30
$Deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($Threshold)

# Function that checks the uptime
function Get-Uptime {
   $os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem
   $uptime = (Get-Date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))
   $display = "Uptime: " + $Uptime.Days + " days" 
   Write-Output $display
}

# Then run a check on all the servers to see if the uptime is longer than the threshold
ForEach ($computer in $computer) 
    {
    If ($uptime -ge $Deadline) 
      {
      Send-MailMessage -From $sender -To $receiver -Subject "Server $computer need to be rebooted" -Body "Server has been up for more than $Threshold days" -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "mailserver.domain.com"
      }
    }

# End of script
```

Comment: Right now I get no result with the script, so any tip on how I can make this work is appreciated

Comment: Well u dont execute the function Get-Uptime in your loop..
So the variable $uptime = $0 = $false

Comment: ok, I'm no programmer, I'm just a server administrator trying to learn powershell. So how should I use the function in the loop then?

Comment: wait i will write it as an answer

Comment: Your function would return a string, so you can't use it in the comparison with `$Deadline`. Also, it queries the last boot time from the local computer, not from `$computer` and calculates the number of days since the last reboot instead of returning the actual date.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The code has more (and more severe) issues than just that misconception/typo.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - You are correct; see the response to comment from bluuf to my answer. VTC retracted.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to execute the function `Get-Uptime` in your loop, also you have to run the Commands remotely on the Computers.

```
# Variables for sending the report
$sender = "serviceaccount@domain.com"
$receiver = "administrator@domain.no"

$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter * -properties operatingsystem | where {$_.operatingsystem -match "server"} | select name

# Set the Threshold Limit and Deadline
$Threshold = -30
$Deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($Threshold)

$Remote_Credentials = Get-Credentials
#Run a check on all the servers to see if the uptime is longer than the threshold
    ForEach ($computer in $computers) 
    {
        #Remotly invoke the Commands to check uptime
        $uptime = (Get-Date) - ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).ConvertToDateTime((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $computer -Credential $Remote_Credentials).lastbootuptime))

        If ($uptime -ge $Deadline) 
        {
          Send-MailMessage -From $sender -To $receiver -Subject "Server $computer need to be rebooted" -Body "Server has been up for more than $Threshold days" -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "mailserver.domain.com"a
        }
    }
```

If you dont want to sent an email for each computer passing the limit and instead write only one email for the computers you can change the last part:

```
If ($uptime -ge $Deadline) 
            {
              $subject += "Server $computer need to be rebooted" -Body "Server has been up for more than $Threshold days"
            }
```

And send the Mail after the Foreach loop:

```
Send-MailMessage -From $sender -To $receiver -Subject $Subject -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "mailserver.domain.com"
#Dont forget to reset $subject afterwards: $subject = $0
```

Comment: You probably don't need to use `Invoke-Command`; `Get-WMIObject` (and the now-preferred `Get-CIMInstance`) takes a `-ComputerName` parameter, which will successfully retrieve the class instances if the user's current credentials are also valid for the named computer.

Comment: I tried to change the script like you suggesten. But I get this error message: 
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: @Tomas Well ofc you have to enable powershell remoting on the computer you want to check with the get-wmi command.
Please make sure it is enabled and try again.

Comment: @Tomas well i looked into the Exception and it seems it isnt based on the enabling of PS-Remote, maybe look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516735/difference-between-invoke-command-and-query-directly

You may have to user Invoke-Command instead of Get-WmiObject.

Answer (score 1):

Your ForEach loop is not correctly structured; you are trying to use as the "index variable" (`$computer`) the same variable (`$computer`) that contains the set that you are iterating over.  Change the `$computer = Import-CSV ...` to `$computers = ...`, and change the `ForEach` to `ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) ...`.

Additionally, as has been pointed out by others (and which I initially overlooked), you never call your `Get-Uptime` function. As `Get-WMIObject` takes a `-ComputerName` parameter, I'd rewrite it:

```
function Get-Uptime {
    param (
        [string]$ComputerName = "localhost"
    )
    $os = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
    $uptime = (Get-Date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))
    return $uptime
}
```

and call it in your `ForEach` loop:

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    if ((Get-Uptime -ComputerName $Computer) -ge $Deadline) {
        Send-MailMessage ...
    } #ENDIF
} #END-ForEach
```

Comment: The custom function (Get-Uptime) that the questioneer wrote is never actually called in the foreach loop so this code will never run (besides the incorrect structured loop).

Comment: @bluuf - You're correct; I focussed on his complaint about his `ForEach` not working, and overlooked that the code as presented is essentially unusable for the declared purpose.