# Difference between Invoke-Command and query directly

Tags: powershell, wmi, rpc, powershell-remoting

I'm currently working on a script that queries the disk information from a server. I'm stack with a problem and I really don't know whats going on here. May you can help me.

**The following code is working (ComputerName replaced):**

```
$space1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "xxxxxx" -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
}
```

This code works kinda well and may takes around 2 seconds to execute.
After some experimenting I found a way how I can query it even faster. With all other servers it works fine, but for this server it simply doesn't work. Here' the code:

```
$space1 = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "xxxxxx" -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
```

This code takes around ~40 seconds to run, and then ends with the following error:

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x800706BA)
At line:1 char:10
+ $test1 = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "xxxxxx" -Class Win32_LogicalD ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Can someone explain to me why it works fine with `Invoke-Command` but not when I use the `ComputerName` param on the `Get-WmiObject` directly? As said, for all my other servers this works fine and the code is faster so I would like to always use this code.

**What I've done so far:**

- I checked the server for DNS and I tested similar commands.
- Tried some other WmiObject commands, seems like always the RPC is not available.

**What I think the problem could be:**

I think the RPC protocol is disabled on the server. Does somebody know how to check that? Haven't found really anything that worked through Google...

**What seems special:**

CimInstance commands works. Do they use the RPC protocol too, or do they use another protocol? Haven't found any information on that one. Here the code I tested with:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName "ccccc" -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
```

Comment: I looks to me like a COM's permissions issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft's [WMI troubleshooting guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394603.aspx) classifies the error as a firewall issue:

> **Error**
>   `0x800706BA–HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)`
>   Firewall issue or server not available.
>
> **Possible Issues**
>   The computer really doesn't exist The Windows Firewall is blocking the connection
>
> **Solution**
>   Connecting to Vista: `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes`. Connecting to downlevel: Allow the "Remote Administration" rule in Windows Firewall.

The difference between `Get-WmiObject` on the one hand and `Get-CimInstance` and `Invoke-Command` on the other hand is that the former uses DCOM for the network communication, while the latter use WinRM. See the article ["Should I use CIM or WMI with Windows PowerShell"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/02/08/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/) on the Scripting Guys blog for more information about the differences between WMI and CIM.

The [DCOM protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161377.aspx) is based on RPC and uses port 135/tcp for the RPC endpoint mapper, which then assigns a random port between 1024 and 65535 for the actual RPC connection. [WinRM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/22/new-default-ports-for-ws-management-and-powershell-remoting/) on the other hand uses only one of two ports: 5985 for HTTP connections an 5986 for HTTPS connections, so it's a lot more firewall-friendly, and enabling WinRM/PowerShell Remoting already opens the ports in the firewall. That's most likely the reason why `Invoke-Command` and `Get-CimInstance` work, while `Get-WmiObject` doesn't.

As for the RPC protocol being disabled: that's not possible. Windows relies heavily on RPC for internal communication. If you actually disabled the protocol Windows would simply stop working.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for this answer! Really appreciate that one! Really competent and short answer, with all Information I need. So I'll talk to the firewall guy, since I'm not allowed to do this changes by myself. I'll l ook with them what we can do. Thank you!